# Handling hashed passwords stored as varbinary in SQL Server and classic ASP

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, vbscript, passwords, varbinary

All,

Sorry in advance - I'm a novice in most of the topics below (SQL, ASP). Anyway...

I've  got a pretty simple web app that requires users to log in with a user name and password.

The front end creates a salted SHA1 hash of the password, and posts it (along with the user's name) to an ASP page.

That ASP page takes the data, calls a stored procedure in the SQL Server database, and passes the users name and hashed password; the stored procedure writes the info to the 'users' table.

The password column's type in the table is varbinary.

As far as I can tell, when the ASP gets the password (password = Request.Form("password")), it's a String.

I can 'trick' SQL Server into handling it as a varbinary if I create the query this way:

query = "EXEC sp_save_user @username='" & username & "', @password=0x" & password

IOW - I'm prepending an "0x" to the password string.

However, I've read that it's a better practice to use a parameterized query:

E.g.: SET objParam = objCommand.CreateParameter("@password",204, 1, 40, password)

However, this fails because the parameter is supposed to be binary (204), but password is a string.

So, how do I convert a string like "4a5e6a8d521ed487b81c91e131cf27e8dae9b783" to a binary in ASP?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember the days when I used to bash my head on this kind of thing. I suggest you get an upgrade to ASP.Net, but in the mean time the following code (VBScript) should do what you want:

```
<%

Dim result

main()

function main()

    Dim userName : userName = "Martin"
    Dim data : data = "4a5e6a8d521ed487b81c91e131cf27e8dae9b783"

    Dim db: Set db = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    db.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa;Password=password1;Initial Catalog=Test;Data Source=(local)"

    Dim cmd : Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    cmd.ActiveConnection = db

    cmd.CommandText = "dbo.[sp_save_user]"
    cmd.CommandType = 4    
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@UserName", 200, 1, 50, userName)
    Dim bytes : bytes = stringToBinary(data)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Password", 204, 1, LenB(bytes), bytes)
    cmd.Execute()

    db.Close

    result = "done"

end function

function stringToBinary(str)
    dim ahex
    for i=0 to len(str) - 1 step 2
        Dim strDigit1 
        Dim strDigit2
        strDigit1 = Ucase(Mid(str, i+1, 1))
        strDigit2 = Ucase(Mid(str, i+2, 1))

        Dim byteDigit1
        Dim byteDigit2
        byteDigit1 = InStr("0123456789ABCDEF", strDigit1) - 1
        byteDigit2 = InStr("0123456789ABCDEF", strDigit2) - 1

        ahex = ahex & ChrB((byteDigit1 * 16) + byteDigit2)
    next   

    stringToBinary = ahex          
end function
%>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><%= result %></h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have scope to change the DB... more specifically the Stored Procedure?

Why not just accept the hash as a string and CAST it to varbinary within the SProc?

Reading further, there is no built-in String -> Varbinary function in SQL Server, but [this function](http://blogs.msdn.com/rextang/archive/2008/01/13/7091118.aspx) has been offered as an easy solution,

Comment: It is just as easy to do the conversion in VBScript and that way you get to keep your database interface clean for when you upgrade to a newer UI technology.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit unrelated, but I'm  wondering, if you are salting the hash on the client, how are you exactly keeping the salt secure?

Comment: My understanding is that it's not critical to secure the salt - the point of salting passwords it that it will prevent anyone from using a predefined list of hashed passwords. In other words, if someone got my salt, they could then create a NEW dictionary of hashed versions of every possible password + my salt, but that's sufficiently time-consuming as to make it not worth the effort. Of course, I'm not an expert, so take this with a grain of salt. ;-)