# I have an encrypted value, why wont it go into the varbinary field?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I just need to fix a couple of bad records. I am able to swap the month with the year and re-encrypt. But when I try and put it into the MS SQL SERVER varbinary field again it is getting truncated. What is the correct way to update the table with the new encrypted values?

```
Conn.Open strDSN
Dim sql : sql = "Select * FROM tmpRefill WHERE CC <> 'NULL' AND CustId = 9944"
rs.Open sql, Conn

Dim custId, email, cc, newCC, upSQL
Do Until rs.EOF
Response.Write rs("CustId")
Response.Write("<br />")
Response.Write rs("email")
Response.Write("<br />")
cc = EnCrypt(rs("CC"))
Response.Write cc
Response.Write("<br />")
cc = Split(cc,"-")
newCC = cc(0) & "-" & cc(2) & "-" & cc(1) & "-" & cc(3)
Response.Write newCC
Response.Write("<br />")
newCC = EnCrypt(newCC)
Response.Write newCC
Response.Write("<br />")
Response.Write("<br /><br />")
rs.MoveNext
Loop

upSQL = "UPDATE tmpRefill SET CC = CONVERT(VARBINARY(500), '" & newCC & "') WHERE CustId = 9944"
Conn.Execute (upSQL)
```

The datatype on the table column is varbinary(500) so I dont understand why I have to convert it to insert it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775702/handling-hashed-passwords-stored-as-varbinary-in-sql-server-and-classic-asp/776754#776754) that shows how to use both a parameterized query as well as passing binary data in.